# JavaScript: Multiple promise objects being chained

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, ecmascript-6

Tools: ES6 JavaScript

Maybe this is all gravy. I just need a quick peer review to make sure I'm not doing (something ugly/sinning).

I'm grabbing promises from different modules and then chaining them. I can't find a good example of **chaining multiple promise objects(not to be confused with chaining a promise with sequenced callbacks)** and so the syntax confuses me because I'm not sure if I start nesting promises syntactically or not.

I feel like promise.all should be in the mix, **but since I have some functions(callbacks if you wil) to define success and failure operations layered in the middle - using promise.all syntactically is confusing.**

For example lets get 2 promises. We finish the 1st and then call the 2nd. If they both succeed - do some success operation,otherwise a failure operations, finally do a finishing callback with a success or failure object for the bootstrapping:

```
bootStrapProgram = function(callback){

    var promise1 = module1.getPromise1();
    var promise2 = module2.getPromise2();

      promise1.then(promise2.then(successOperation,failureOperation).then(callback));

}

successOperation = function(){
  //Shoot out confetti or something I don't care.
}

failureOperation = function(){
 //I dunno, Fire Le Missles!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to know when both operations have completed, then you can do this:

```
var promise1 = module1.getPromise1();
var promise2 = module2.getPromise2();
Promise.all(promise1, promise2).then(function() {
    // success here
}, function(reason) {
    // error here
});
```

If you want to run one operation before the other, then you can serialize them like this:

```
module1.getPromise1().then(function(value1) {
    return module2.getPromise2();
}).then(function(value2) {
    // success here
}, function(reason) {
    // error here
});
```

Comment: Would need to pass in value 1 if the second promise needed it? Ex: .then(function(value1) {return module2.getPromise2(value1);

Comment: @NickPineda - if you want to pass `value1` to `getPromise2()`, you are welcome to do that in the second example.  I don't see where you stated that as a requirement so I did not show that, but you're free to do that if you want.  You can't do that in the first example, because both operations are started at the same time, thus one result cannot be used in the other.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` is not necessarily syntactically confusing, what you're doing potentially is. Your code suggests that promise1 and promise2 must be processed in that temporal order, which is not necessarily true.

```
var promise1 = foo.get(), promise2 = bar.get();

promise1.catch(failure1Fn);
promise2.catch(failure2Fn);

Promise
    .all([promise1, promise2])
    .then(bothSucceededFn);
```

Now you keep the separate error handling but have the all succeeded case dealt with. Don't forget that just because you call `Promise.all` on an array of Promises doesn't mean you can't deal with each individually as well.

If you don't really need to have the separate error handling then just

```
Promise
    .all([promise1, promise2])
    .then(bothSucceededFn)
    .catch(failureFn);
```

Comment: A related clarifying question : In the promise.all chain is there a value(coming from resolves being called) that is being passed down the chain? promise1---val1-->promise2--->val2 --->bothSucceededFn.

Comment: `Promise.all` returns an array of the values from all the promises if they all succeed, or the first error if one fails. One way to think about it (per James Cogland) is that it turns things inside out: you give it a list of Promises and it gives you back a Promise of a list. So if `foo.get()` succeeds and returns 'foo' and `bar.get()` succeeds and returns 'bar' then the `.then` handler attached to `Promise.all` will be passed an array like so: ['foo', 'bar']